Linear function/map - different definitions
I am reading some vector calculus and linear algebra too. There a linear function/map is defined as a function/map which has these properties $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, $f(ax) = af(x)$. Here $x,y$ are vectors from $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f(x), f(y)$ are vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$. The $a$ is just an arbitrary real number.
OK, now from this definition, it easily follows that $f$ has the form
$f(x) = f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m) = a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... + a_m x_m$
where $a_i$ are some constant n-dimensional vectors (they are the images of the vectors $e_i$ of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$).
But I've studied very early in school that a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ like $f(x) = kx+b$ is called a linear function. So I am thinking now that in terms of vector calculus and linear algebra this function is not really a linear function unless $b=0$.
So... which one of the two definitions of linear is correct?
And why is this definition of linear different depending on where (in which field of math) you are.

Both definitions are correct. The meaning depends on the context as you have noticed.

Well, the definition of the linear function coming from school is not actually correct. The only correct definition of the linear function comes from Linear Algebra. The functions $f(x) = ax + b$ are called Affine-linear.
To be more precise, the function $f(x)$ is called Affine-linear or Affine function if $f(x) = Ax + b$, for some matrix $A$, and vector $b$. So it is the linear function + translation.
